# Black Scholes/American Put/Martingale Condition

Tags: black-scholes, american-options, martingale

Consider a Black Scholes model with $r \geq 0$. Show that the price of an American Put Option with maturity $T > 0$ is bounded by $\frac{K}{1 + \alpha} {(\frac{\alpha K}{1 + \alpha})}^{\alpha}{S_{0}^{-\alpha}}$.
Hint: find $\alpha > 0$ such that $e^{-rt}S_{t}^{-\alpha}$ is a martingale.

I am trying to work through the hint and when rewriting $e^{-rt}S_{t}^{-\alpha}$ I get $e^{-rt}S_{t}^{-\alpha} = exp(-\alpha \sigma W_t - t(r + \alpha (r-\frac{{\sigma}^2}{2})))$

I know that in case of the GBM the drift has to equal zero for it to be a martingale, which property has to be fulfilled here?

Edit: the condition that my professor wrote:

$r + \alpha (r-\frac{{\sigma}^2}{2}) = \frac{\alpha^2 \sigma^2}{2}$

which leads to a quadratic equation for $\alpha$, but O do not quite understand where is equation comes from.

Comment: There are too many $r$s in that exponential. Hint: It is well known that for a stock not paying dividends $e^{-rt}S_t$ is a martingale under the risk-neutral measure.

Comment: @KurtG., thank you very much, of course there was a mistake with the $rt$ and I corrected it now. And regarding your hint I know that a probability measure Q is risk neutral if $E_{Q}[S_t | F_s] = S_s e^{r(t-s)}$, with that information how can I calculate $\alpha$?

Comment: What we both know now boils down to $\alpha=1\,.$

Comment: @KurtG., thank you for coming back to this thread, I would have $\alpha = -1$, if we use the condition that $e^{-rt}S_t = e^{-rt}{S_t}^{-(-1)}$ is a martingale. My professor wrote a condition today which I don’t quite understand, I edited the post. Do you maybe know where this property comes from?(The quadratic equation also leads to $\alpha = -1$ as one solution.)

Comment: Correct. My mistake. See answer for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

\begin{align}
S_t&=S_0\,e^{rt+\sigma W_t-\sigma^2t/2}\,,&S_t^{-\alpha}=S_0^{-\alpha}\,e^{-\alpha\, r\,t\,-\,\alpha\,\sigma\, W_t\,+\,\alpha\,\sigma^2\,t/2}\,,
\end{align}
\begin{align}
e^{-rt}S_t^{-\alpha}&=S_0^{-\alpha}e^{-(1+\alpha)\,r\,t\,-\,\alpha\,\sigma\, W_t\,+\,\alpha\,\sigma^2\,t/2}\\
&=S_0^{-\alpha}e^{-(1+\alpha)\,r\,t\,+\,(\alpha^2+\alpha)\,\sigma^2\,t/2}\,\underbrace{e^{-\,\alpha\,\sigma\, W_t\,-\,\alpha^2\sigma^2\,t/2}}_{\text{martingale}}\,.
\end{align}
For the whole expression to be a martingale we must have (your professor's quadratic equation):
\begin{align}
-(1+\alpha)r+(\alpha^2+\alpha)\sigma^2/2=0\,.
\end{align}
One solution of that is $\alpha=-1$ but your professor wants a positive solution.
This is
\begin{align}
\alpha&=\frac{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}+r+\sqrt{(\frac{\sigma^2}{2}-r)^2+2\sigma^2r}}{\sigma^2}\\
&=\frac{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}+r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}+r}{\sigma^2}=\frac{2r}{\sigma^2}\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please just tell me the step from the second equality to the third, if I understand correctly you set $-\alpha \sigma W_t$ equal to $\alpha^2 \sigma ^2 t/2$, could you tell me what rule this is?

Comment: The rule for that is that $\mathbb E[e^{X-{\rm Var}(X)/2}]=1$ whenever $X$ is a normal random variable with mean zero. This can easily be verified by applying the normal PDF and completing the square. Its analogue in the martingale world is that $e^{M_t-\langle M\rangle_t/2}$ is a (local) martingale when $M_t$ is one. Proof: Ito's formula.

Comment: Thank you very much